# Forking a repo with the GitHub API with client-side Javascript and OAuth.io

Tags: javascript, github, oauth, github-api

I'm trying to write client-side Javascript that will fork a given GitHub repo. I'm using the OAuth.io service to get an OAuth token with the API scopes set to "public_repo" and "repo"[image: screenshot of oauth.io dashboard].

I'm using [github.js](https://github.com/michael/github) to access the GitHub API, using the `fork` method (in the `makeWebsite` function):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  initializeOAuth();
  setEventListener();
});

var setEventListener = function() {
  $("#button").click(popupOAuth);
};

var initializeOAuth = function() {
  OAuth.initialize("rG-ChpeD0zdiIPoJpK58gN4qMJQ");
};

var popupOAuth = function() {
  OAuth.popup("github").done(makeWebsite);
};

var makeWebsite = function(result) {
  var token = result["token"];

  var github = new Github({
    token: token,
    auth: "oauth"
  });

  var repo = github.getRepo("michael", "github");
  repo.fork(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

When I run this code and complete the OAuth dance, I get the following error:

[image: 404 Not Found]

Comment: Does *any* GitHub API call work for you? Any destructive API call?

Comment: Yes. `repo.show(function(err, myRepo) { console.log(myRepo); });` gets me all [this](https://gist.github.com/adelevie/6dcf1b03ccfb0d407d00). It makes me think there's a scoping issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
var makeWebsite = function(ghClient) {
  ghClient.post("/repos/MyInternetWebsite/template/forks").done(cb);
};
```

Looks like the problem was with github.js. Turns out OAuth.io provides simple http access on its own that handles authentication. For what it's worth, all that's need to fork is the `public_repo` scope.